# Python listener doesn't detect key

Tags: python, python-3.x, listener

This code, down here, is supposed to count how many times do you press the spacebar, and reset to zero when you press q. It counts well, but does not reset the counter when q is pressed, and I have absolutely no idea why, even after checking docs and other questions like mine.

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def on_press(key):
    global aaa
    global nonpresd
    if key == 'q':
        aaa=4
        nonpresd = True
    elif nonpresd:
        if key == Key.space:
            aaa+=4
            print(aaa)
            nonpresd = False    
    #print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
def on_release(key):
    global nonpresd

    nonpresd = True
    #print('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

while True:
    aaa=4
    nonpresd = True
    with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: I guess `key` is never equal to the string `'q'`. Did you check that the code under `key == 'q'` is ever executed? What do you get when you add `print(repr(key))` at the top of `on_press` and press Q? (Or just uncomment the print statements you already have)

Comment: should it be `key.char == 'q'`?